# How can I make the ITEAD PN532 work on the R-Pi via UART?

Tags: gpio, uart, nfc

I have used the Adafruit PN532 before on the R-Pi (A and B+) via UART and it works just fine but I haven’t been able to make it work for the ITEAD. The ITEAD supports I2C, SPI and UART. On this link, they explain on detail how to make it work for I2C and SPI but UART: http://blog.iteadstudio.com/raspberry-pi-drives-itead-pn532-nfc-module-with-libnfc/#comments. I have tried different configurations on my .conf file without success. I'm using the 8-pin port since the 26-pin port seems to be for I2C and SPI only.

Any idea will be really appreciated.